# How can I add a new JSON node, nested an unknown number of levels, to an existing JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, machine-learning

Recently, I stumbled across the following image, describing a console application which attempts to guess the animal that the user is thinking of by asking a series of questions and updating the questions asked if it guesses incorrectly:

[image: algo]

Despite knowing nothing about machine learning, I figured that this was a pretty simple program to replicate using decision trees, so I bashed together the below python code:

```
import json

json_file = open("DecisionTree1.json", "r")
decision_tree = json.loads(json_file.read())
partial_decision_tree = decision_tree["start"]


def get_user_input(prompt, validation):
    if validation == "yes_no":
        print(prompt)
        while True:
            answer = input()
            if answer.lower() not in ('yes', 'no'):
                print("Please enter 'Yes' or 'No'")
            else:
                return answer.lower()
    elif validation == "not_empty":
        while True:
            answer = input(prompt + "\n")
            if answer != "":
                return answer.lower()


def create_new_node(guess):
    correct_answer = get_user_input("What animal were you thinking of?", "not_empty")
    new_question = get_user_input("Enter a question for which the answer is 'Yes' for " + correct_answer + " and 'No' for " + guess, "not_empty")
    new_node = json.loads('{"question": "' + new_question + '","children":{"yes": {"question": "Is it a ' + correct_answer + '?","children": null},"no": {"question": "Is it a rabbit?","children": null}}}')
    return json.dumps(new_node)


answer_array = list()


while partial_decision_tree["children"]:
    answer = get_user_input(partial_decision_tree["question"], "yes_no")
    answer_array.append(answer)
    partial_decision_tree = partial_decision_tree["children"][answer]

if get_user_input(partial_decision_tree["question"], "yes_no") == "no":
    select_conditions = '["start"]'
    for answer in answer_array:
        select_conditions += '["children"]["' + answer + '"]'
    query = "decision_tree" + select_conditions + " = '" + create_new_node(partial_decision_tree["question"].split(" ")[-1][0:len(partial_decision_tree["question"].split(" ")[-1])-1]) + "'"
    exec(query)
```

The JSON file DecisionTree1.json contains the following data, which is supposed to represent a (very small) decision tree:

```
{
    "start":
    {
        "question": "Is it smaller than a bicycle?",
        "children": 
        {
            "yes": {
                "question": "Is it a rabbit?",
                "children": null
            },
            "no": {
                "question": "Is it an elephant?",
                "children": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea should be that, if the user guesses incorrectly, then the leaf node that the program is looking at when it makes its guess should be replaced with a new internal node which provides an additional level of filtering on the programs guess.

In terms of the JSON, this means:

1. Replacing the "question" attribute of the node containing the current guess with the question that the user has specified
2. Updating the "children" attribute of the node to, rather than being null, contain two new nodes which each constitute a guess (i.e. a leaf node)

My question is **how can I update the JSON within the file in this way?**

At present, the `query` variable in my python updates the JSON so that the the value of the "children" attribute becomes a *string*, rather than two sub-nodes.

EDIT: Following martineau's comment, here is an example of how the JSON should look after being updated:

Suppose that the user is thinking of a tortoise. As it stands, the program would incorrectly guess their animal to be a rabbit. When asked to "type in a question for which the answer is yes for a tortoise and no for a rabbit", they might specify the question "Does it have a shell?". The existing JSON (as shown above) should then become

```
{
    "start":
    {
        "question": "Is it smaller than a bicycle?",
        "children": 
        {
            "yes": {
                "question": "Does it have a shell?",
                "children":
                {
                    "yes": {
                        "question": "Is it a tortoise?",
                        "children": null
                    },
                    "no": {
                        "question": "Is it a rabbit?",
                        "children": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "no": {
                "question": "Is it an elephant?",
                "children": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO your question is too abstract. Please [edit] it and show a concrete example including a "before" and "after" of what the JSON should look like after a certain user input — and that could be used to as a testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problematic is quite interesting indeed. I gave it a shot but before I explain the solution, I'd like to pinpoint a few conceptual issues I saw during my work on your code. Here are the changes I made:

1. Your **JSON structure** is not quite easy to parse in my opinion. I opted for something a bit more comfortable by removing the "children" node since there are always only two possible choices: *yes* or *no*
2. Don't get confused: once loaded, a JSON message such as yours is nothing more than a simple `dict` with other `dict`s embedded. You don't need to write anything in the JSON file by yourself because Python knows how to translate such structures.
3. Using iteration in a tree hierarchy is known to be a bad choice in terms of performances and ease of use. Using **recursion** is much straighforward and I strongly encourage you to learn how it can be effective in some cases such as this one
4. I found the **validation** to be something like a side effect of your iterative process. You don't need that extra `validation` parameter everywhere in my opinion, but feel free to integrate it back when you'd really need it
5. I "optimized" your code by adding a few things such as the `if __name__ == "__main__"` which purpose is to check if the Python file is started as a module or is embedded in another solution. You also misused the `open` directive to read and write files. I fixed those for you

Hopefully you'll learn a few tricks by reading my solution, that's at least why I'm writing it. I do not pretend to know everything, so there might be mistakes as well but it should help you going forward with your project. I would typically expect you to split the learning part of the script into other functions.

The main script:

```py
import json

def get_question_node(tree, question):
    """
    Finds the node which contains the given question, recursively.

    :param tree: the tree level from where to start
    :param question: the question to find
    """
    if 'question' in tree and tree['question'] == question:
        # If the current node contains the question, return it
        return tree
    if 'yes' in tree and tree['yes']:
        # If there is a 'yes' node, check its underlying question
        result = get_question_node(tree['yes'], question)
        if result:
            return result
    if 'no' in tree and tree['no']:
        # If there is a 'no' node, check its underlying question
        result = get_question_node(tree['no'], question)
        if result:
            return result

def guess(tree):
    """
    Guesses based on a user's input and the given decision tree.

    :param tree: the current node to go through for the user
    """
    # A question has been found
    question = tree['question']
    answer = input(question + '\n').lower()

    if answer == 'yes':
        if tree['yes']:
            # There are sub questions, ask them
            return guess(tree['yes'])
        else:
            # Final question answered correctly, so we won!
            print('Yay, I guessed correctly!')
            return True
    elif answer == 'no':
        if tree['no']:
            # There are sub questions, ask them
            return guess(tree['no'])
        else:
            # No more question, create a new one and "learn"
            correct_answer = input('What animal were you thinking of?\n')
            new_question = input('Enter a question for which the answer is "Yes" for {}\n'.format(correct_answer))

            # Return to the caller to fix the order of questions
            return {
                'old': tree['question'],
                'new': new_question,
                'correct_answer': correct_answer,
            }
    else:
        # Answer needs to be yes or no, any other answer loops back to the question
        print('Sorry, I didn\'t get that... let\'s try again!')
        return guess(tree)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load and parse the decision tree
    with open("DecisionTree1.json", "r") as json_file:
        decision_tree = json.loads(json_file.read())

    # Start guessing
    partial_decision_tree = decision_tree["start"]
    result = guess(partial_decision_tree)

    if type(result) == dict:
        # Ah! We learned something new, let's swap questions
        question_node = get_question_node(partial_decision_tree, result['old'])
        new_yes = {
            'question': 'Is it a {}?'.format(result['correct_answer']),
            'yes': None,
            'no': None,
        }
        new_no = {
            'question': question_node['question'],
            'yes': question_node['yes'],
            'no': question_node['no'],
        }

        question_node['no'] = new_no
        question_node['yes'] = new_yes
        question_node['question'] = result['new']

    # Persist changes to the decision tree file
    with open('DecisionTree1.json', 'w') as tree_file:
        json.dump(decision_tree, tree_file, indent=4)
```

And the improved `DecisionTree1.json`:

```
{
    "start":
    {
        "question": "Is it smaller than a bicycle?",
        "yes": {
            "question": "Is it a rabbit?",
            "yes": null,
            "no": null
        },
        "no": {
            "question": "Is it an elephant?",
            "yes": null,
            "no": null
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I answered your question.